# How can I fairly distribute identical goods bought at different prices amongst customers so that they all pay the same price?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to allocate a product bought at different prices to different clients in a fair way. Initially, each of the $n$ client asked for a specific quantity of the product  $a_1\ldots a_n$

The goods were bought in $m$ batches, every batch having a different quantity of goods $q$ which was paid a different price $p$ : $(q_1,p_1)\cdots(q_m,p_m)$

Obviously, the total quantity of items bought matches what was initially ordered $\sum a = \sum e$

I'm trying to find a matrix M(x,y) for which :

1. Each client receives the quantity of goods he ordered :  $\sum M(i,y) = a_i$
2. The average price paid par each client is as close as possible to the "fair price", which is the average price of the global order $ |\frac {\sum M(i,y) p_i )}{ a_i} - \frac { \sum q_m,p_m }{ \sum a_n  } |= \epsilon$

What would be an efficient way of doing that? I've looked into the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm), but I'm not sure it would be adapted in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question! Did you also discover this problem as part of financial order execution (filling brokerage orders for multiple accounts)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate the average cost of an item by summing the total spent and dividing by the number of items?  Then charge each customer that number times the quantity shipped to them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. The "goods" I'm talking about are financial products, and they need to be sold to the end client at the exact price they were bought at.

Comment: The trick here is that you have to be accountable for each individual and indivisible unit allocated. Thus, we are still solving for the integer values of the matrix $M(x,y)$